# Pourquoi on écrit "son armée"

Tags: grammaire, genre

Pourquoi on écrit "son armée" (féminin) dans "Le roi part pour la guerre avec son armée"? C'est **une** armée: pourquoi pas "sa armée" alors qu'on écrit "Le père aime sa fille"?

I'm not sure about my French, so I'm gonna ask this question in English as well ;-) Why we write "son armée" whereas we write "sa fille". Both words are feminine and I can't find the difference.

Comment: Oh, ok. I read about it, but I've completely forgot that rule. I've googled before posing a question, but I found nothing satisfying my curiosity. Thanks, Stéphane.